# Windows application to monitor data I/O per program

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Relevant System Info:

- Win10Pro
- Samsung QVO 860 2TB
- 6 HDDs

I have recently calculated my system is writing approximately 1.9GB per hour to my new SSD and I wish to log which programs are the most consuming. I do not wish to simply see the realtime data speeds reported by task manager, most programs are not constantly running, I wish to see a report, for example, a weekly chart.

I run several servers, occasionally from the main drive and wish to see specific programs which write high amounts over time. I see programs such as "Storage Reports Management" available for Windows Server, not Pro. Are there any reasonable alternatives?

I'm not interested in specific data or recovery, simply throughput logs.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I've slightly rephrased your question, as our site doesn't cover [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or "best approaches" (we focus on recommending software). Good luck!

Comment: Well, still no answer to a software solution, but I found the data drain. Turns out a very large daily server backup of 20+GB was driving the average way up. Don't let your files get out of hand, kids. Looking for an incremental solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Process Monitor

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Uncheck the boxes for registry,processes,networking, and you should be left with file system.

Alternatively:
[image]

Check
[image]
You can uncheck the Read if you want.

[image]

I can even sort by "I/O write bytes"

Comment: Would need one with persistence as the processes would close and reopen, if I am correct, both of these programs will restart at 0 each time.